# Is there a Finance Overflow?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, site-proposal

We have a Stack Overflow and a Math Overflow.

Has anyone thought of setting up a Finance Overflow to discuss derivatives and financial instruments used in banks?

This would be a good Q&A site!

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 17):

[Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) is the correct site..  For those curious, it also answers to the name http://basicallymoney.com and has absorbed the Q&A that they developed during their Stack Exchange 1.0 adventure.

Comment: said absorption has been .. problematic .. largely due to weak metas (governance, leadership) based on SE 1.0 history of, well, *not having any*. As it turns out, contrary to my previous beliefs on the matter, meta isn't murder, but in fact sort of fundamentally necessary for any actual community to form..

Answer (score 12):

I know of these two proposals on Area 51:

[Personal Finance and Money](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money)

[Quantitative Finance](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117/quantitative-finance)

The second one is most likely along the lines you describe.

Comment: both are now launched, too.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the answers given

https://economics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EkaterinaIvanovaiceja.net ask economics meta? but personally i'd like to know. tag me here with a link if you ask please

Answer (score 1):

There are currently some money-based sites already...have a look at the listing on https://web.archive.org/web/20100413233431/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites, and scroll down to the "Money" section.

The original question was deleted as it was nowadays referred to as "Stack Exchange 1.0". The official current site list URL is  https://stackexchange.com/sites, but it doesn't include a Money category.